# CSS Grid how to select row to add hover effect?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table, css-grid

I need to select a row to add a `hover` effect on it. I'm trying to wrap all cells in a row with a `div`, but all markup is destroyed. Does anyone have any idea how to do it? Is this even possible?

Check here for full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-easley-w5rrg

```
const TableWrapperUI = styled.div `
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    ${props => props.columns && props.columns},
    fit-content(400px)
  );
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  > span {
    padding: 5px;
    justify-self: left;
    :hover {
      background: #dbeaf4;
    }
  }`;

const LineUI = styled.div `
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
`;
```

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48108879/8620333

Comment: duplicate: [How to target a specific column or row in CSS Grid Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46308048/3597276)

Comment: Do any of the solutions below solve your issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`display: contents;` to the rescue!

*Kinda.*

Depending on your [browser support and/or accessibility requirements](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents), we can achieve the effect you want, using the general structure you have, with the relatively new [`display: contents` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_contents).

Describing `display: contents` is somewhat difficult, so I'll point to this excellent [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/).

To use it, we'll wrap each group of `<span>` elements in a row into a `<div>` with `display: contents`. This allows us to target the `div:hover > span` elements and apply a background color.

There were a few others small changes required to your styling, like making the `<span>` elements fill the available width. Here's a working example:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(15%, max-content));
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.parent span {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
}

.row {
  display: contents;
}

.row:hover span {
  background-color: #dbeaf4;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>Knowledge process outsourcing land the plane yet to be inspired is to become creative, innovative and energized we want this</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>We need to socialize the comms with the wider stakeholder community</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**With React and Styled Components**

Now that we have the CSS working, we can put this back into a styled-components. The main change I've made to your code is to use the `<LineUI />` component to wrap each row, along with the new CSS from above.

```js
const titles = [
  "Id",
  "Type",
  "Name",
  "Category",
  "Client",
  "Date",
  "Watched",
  "Amount",
  "State",
  "Delete"
];

const data = [
  {
    id: 23,
    type: "test",
    name: "joaaaahnny cageasdasdasd cageasdasdasd cageasdasdasd cageasdasdasd",
    category: "selasdasler",
    client: "custom",
    date: "01-01-2019",
    watched: "yes",
    amount: 1231,
    state: "pending",
    delete: "button"
  },
  {
    id: 211,
    type: "test",
    name: "johnny cage",
    category: "seller",
    client: "custsdsom",
    date: "01-01-2019",
    watched: "yes",
    amount: 1231,
    state: "pending",
    delete: "button"
  },
  {
    id: 2222,
    type: "test",
    name: "johnny cage",
    category: "seller",
    client: "custom",
    date: "01-01-2019",
    watched: "yes",
    amount: 1231,
    state: "pending",
    delete: "button"
  },
  {
    id: 2222,
    type: "test",
    name: "johnny cage",
    category: "seller",
    client: "custom",
    date: "01-01-2019",
    watched: "yes",
    amount: 1231,
    state: "pending",
    delete: "button"
  },
  {
    id: 2222,
    type: "test",
    name: "johnny cage",
    category: "seller",
    client: "custom",
    date: "01-01-2019",
    watched: "yes",
    amount: 1231,
    state: "pending",
    delete: "button"
  },
  {
    id: 2222,
    type: "test",
    name: "johnny cage",
    category: "seller",
    client: "custom",
    date: "01-01-2019",
    watched: "yes",
    amount: 1231,
    state: "pending",
    delete: "button"
  },
  {
    id: 2222,
    type: "test",
    name: "johnny cage",
    category: "seller",
    client: "custom",
    date: "01-01-2019",
    watched: "yes",
    amount: 1231,
    state: "pending",
    delete: "button"
  }
];

const TableWrapperUI = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    ${props => props.columns && props.columns},
    minmax(auto, max-content)
  );
  padding: 5px;

  > * {
    padding: 5px;
  }
`;

const LineUI = styled.div`
  display: contents;
  
  > * {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
  }

  :hover > * {
    background-color: #dbeaf4;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: visible;
  }
`;

const Table = ({ children, titles, data }) => {
  const [amountColumns, setAmountColumns] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setAmountColumns(titles.length);
  }, []);

  const displayData = data => {
    return data.map((x, idx) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={idx}>
          <LineUI>
            {Object.keys(x).map((value, ids) => (
              <span key={ids}>{x[value]}</span>
            ))}
          </LineUI>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });
  };

  const displayTitles = titles => {
    return titles.map((title, idx) => {
      return <span key={idx}>{title}</span>;
    });
  };

  return (
    amountColumns > 0 && (
      <TableWrapperUI columns={amountColumns}>
        {displayTitles(titles)}
        {displayData(data)}
      </TableWrapperUI>
    )
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table columns={10} titles={titles} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/4.3.2/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I highly advise anyone to not use display: content for now if what you are making will be available to the general population for any kinds of users because of IE lack of support and safari bugs.

Comment: The one bummer with this approach is that column-gap will cause gaps to appear between the spans.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot select a whole row from a child grid, but you can fake it if it's about highlighting the background.

```
const TableWrapperUI = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;/* demo, to show overflow cut off */
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    ${props => props.columns && props.columns},
    fit-content(400px)
  );
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  > span {
    padding: 5px;
    justify-self: left;
    position: relative;  
    :hover {
      background: #dbeaf4;
    }
    :hover::before, ::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      background: inherit;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: -100vw;
      right: -100vw;
    }
    :hover::before {
      z-index:-1
    }
  }
`;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-colden-m34od

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but there is some bugs. It only hovers when I point on span. Is possible make hover for whole row? And that hover goes out of bounds of my table

Comment: Add overflow : hidden to the parent (see CSS comments) ,  make  the pseudo any time and only change color on  hover.

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov from my comment https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-colden-m34od

Answer (score 0):

Here is Grid-based Solution, Use two different rows with a grid.

1) Header row with grid

2) Table grid body with grid

RefCode this link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/hopeful-pascal-hfdzx

Updated CSS:

```
const TableRowUI = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    ${props => props.columns && props.columns},
    1fr
  );
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  > span {
    padding: 5px;
    justify-self: left;
  }
`;

const TableHeadUI = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    ${props => props.columns && props.columns},
    1fr
  );
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  > span {
    padding: 5px;
    justify-self: left;
  }
`;
```

Final code snippet:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/hopeful-pascal-hfdzx

Answer (score -2):

Make it simple to use `table` instead of `span`.

> Codesandbox Example - [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-pine-4fyut)

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
}

table tbody tr:hover {
  background: #dbeaf4;
}

table tbody td {
  border-top: 1px solid #dbeaf4;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Watched</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>joaaaahnny cageasdasdasd cageasdasdasd cageasdasdasd cageasdasdasd</td>
      <td>selasdasler</td>
      <td>custom</td>
      <td>01-01-2019</td>
      <td>yes</td>
      <td>1231</td>
      <td>pending</td>
      <td>button</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>211</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>johnny cage</td>
      <td>seller</td>
      <td>custsdsom</td>
      <td>01-01-2019</td>
      <td>yes</td>
      <td>1231</td>
      <td>pending</td>
      <td>button</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>johnny cage</td>
      <td>seller</td>
      <td>custom</td>
      <td>01-01-2019</td>
      <td>yes</td>
      <td>1231</td>
      <td>pending</td>
      <td>button</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>johnny cage</td>
      <td>seller</td>
      <td>custom</td>
      <td>01-01-2019</td>
      <td>yes</td>
      <td>1231</td>
      <td>pending</td>
      <td>button</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>johnny cage</td>
      <td>seller</td>
      <td>custom</td>
      <td>01-01-2019</td>
      <td>yes</td>
      <td>1231</td>
      <td>pending</td>
      <td>button</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>johnny cage</td>
      <td>seller</td>
      <td>custom</td>
      <td>01-01-2019</td>
      <td>yes</td>
      <td>1231</td>
      <td>pending</td>
      <td>button</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>johnny cage</td>
      <td>seller</td>
      <td>custom</td>
      <td>01-01-2019</td>
      <td>yes</td>
      <td>1231</td>
      <td>pending</td>
      <td>button</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```