# CSS :hover for highliting multiple td cells

Tags: html, css, hover

In a table, upon hovering on one `td` cell, I want to highlight multiple `td` cells in the same row.

What I have currently is to use classes on each `td` like this:

```
        <tr>
            <td>v1_a</td>
            <td class='c1'>v1_b1</td>
            <td class='c1'>v1_b2</td>
            <td class='c2'>v1_c1</td>
            <td class='c2'>v1_c2</td>
        </tr>
```

and have CSS like this:

```
tbody td.c1:hover,
tbody td.c1:hover ~ .c1,
tbody td.c2:hover,
tbody td.c2:hover ~ .c2 {
    background-color: #CCffff;
}
```

then I can partially achieve what I want: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snb9a45y/58/)

However, it is not exactly what I want. It highlights both `col_b1` and `col_b2` when I hover on `col_b1`, but not when I hover on `col_b2`. I want to highlight both of these columns whenever the pointer is on one of the cells.

Is there a simple solution ideally using only CSS?

Comment: Does it have to be with just CSS? Because you could achieve that with using Javascript.

Comment: If it is not possible solely by CSS, use of JS or JQuery is also fine.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48109479/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use javascript to achieve.

I added an attribute as same-group elements identification to make it more sustainable.

```js
$('.highlight').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('.highlight').removeClass('hover');
  $('.highlight[data-cell="'+$(this).data('cell')+'"]').addClass('hover');
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.hover {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>v1_a</td>
    <td class="highlight" data-cell="c1">c1</td>
    <td class="highlight" data-cell="c1">c1</td>
    <td class="highlight" data-cell="c2">c2</td>
    <td class="highlight" data-cell="c2">c2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>v1_a</td>
    <td class="highlight" data-cell="c3">c3</td>
    <td class="highlight" data-cell="c3">c3</td>
    <td class="highlight" data-cell="c4">c4</td>
    <td class="highlight" data-cell="c4">c4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight full row, when hovering over any of the cell. Then write

```
tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
```

in css file.
If you are not using css file and writing all the styling in html file theln write in head

```
<style>
   tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
</style>
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want to do. I'm aware of ways to highlight whole ```tr``` or a single ```td``` but couldn't figure out multiple ```td```s.

Comment: You mean you want a column to be highlighted? Or multiple cells in a single column.